# Intent putExtra persists

Tags: java, android, android-intent

i'm having an issue with Intents and `putExtra`.
What i want to do is this :
In Activity A(it's not my `MainActivity`),when i click a button,it will close all my activities, send a string and launch my main activity.For testing purposes it will show a test dialog with my string.All good till now,works as i need it to.

The problem is that if i restart my `MainActivity`(and i need to do that,it's something like a shopping list,i need to start a new shopping list) the dialog with the `putExtra` string shows again.

Here are my code snippets :

In Activity A :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Gestionarez.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    intent.putExtra( "paramName", str );
    startActivity( intent );
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    dialog.dismiss();
    dialog.cancel();
}
```

In my `MainActivity`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LoadPref();

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String myParam = extras.getString("paramName");
        ShowAlertMessage(this, "TEST", myParam + "");

    } else {

    }

}
```

And this is how i restart my `MainActivity` when i need to start a new shopping list :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: well ... of course, you just passed in the same intent by using getIntent()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
```

with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Worked great,thanks ! I was using that for such a long while that i didn't pay attention now when i implemented something else.Again,thanks !